# Fixed margin between multiple UILabels

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uilabel, uistoryboard

I have 7 UILabels in a simple UIViewController, I manually adjusted those labels in the Interface Builder, they have all the same margin between them. However, when executing it in simulator i have different margins between the labels, not ordered, on the contrary of what I have in the Interface Builder. What I'm missing? Is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: Did you set up Autosizing constraints in Size inspector?

Comment: @Jeepston: I can't find that feature. I'm in xCode 4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image below shows what your size inspector looks like.  If you are using anything less than iOS 6 then this will where you would configure those autosizing constraints that @Jeepston mentioned.  Unless of course you do it programmatically.

If you are only targeting iOS 6 then I would suggest studying up on auto layout [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2).  This new feature should make this very easy for you

[image: Size Inspector]

Comment: Nice answer and awesome posted guide! Thank you very much. Accepted ;).